# Creating unique action listeners in a loop

Tags: java, swing, event-listener, mouseclick-event

I'm currently trying to create unique action listeners for images on a JPanel. I am essentially displaying the name of a movie with an image of five stars to the right of the name.

The user can click on the stars and a transparent rectangle resizes to the area the users clicked, all of this works correctly, however every star image shares the same mouse click listener so all star images react to the same mouse click event.

I am trying to create a unique event listener for each star image so that they can each be set to different values before clicking a "save" button to store the values. Could anyone give me some advice on how this can be achieved?

```
public void addJPanel() {

    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(0, 2);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    this.setLayout(layout);

    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("stars.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("No image found!");
    }

    JLabel label;

    try {

        for (Media med : cart.getCart().keySet()) {

            label = new JLabel(med.getTitle());

            ratingTxt.add(label);

            this.add(ratingTxt);

            label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));

            ratingImg.add(label);
            ratingImg.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    JLabel label2 = null;
                    ratingImg.removeAll();
                    for (Media med : cart.getCart().keySet()) {

                        label2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Process(img,
                                e.getX())));
                        ratingImg.add(label2);
                    }

                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setSize(600, 250);

                }
            });

            this.add(ratingImg);

        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        label = new JLabel(
                "Nothing to display try doing some shopping first!");
        this.add(label);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's a little bit hard to be sure, but since `ratingImg` is the same for each loop, you're just adding another `MouseListener` to the same object...Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I second the comment above, and also want to mention that your code catches a NPE, something that code should never do. If your code throws a NPE, that means that there's something seriously wrong with it that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Hey guys, I will try get an executable demo up as soon as possible!